# Dell R815 power button does not turn off

Tags: hardware, dell-poweredge, electrical-power

I have powered my R815 on/off using DRAC. That works fine.

But today I had some physical maintenance, and wanted to use the power button. I can turn on the server using the button, but I cannot turn the server off. I have held the button for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button was disabled in BIOS:

F2 > System Security > Power Button > Enabled